# JS - Comparing two values in two arrays doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, arrays

can anyone please help me with this code:

```js
    
var questions =[
  ['how many states?', 1],
  ['how many continents?', 2],
  ['how many legs?', 3]
]

var answers = [];
var rightAnswers = [];
var wrongAnswers = [];


for(i = 0; i<questions.length; i+=1){  
  answers.push(prompt(questions[i][0]).toLowerCase());
  
  if(questions[i][1] === answers[i]){
     // rightAnswers.push(questions[i][0]) 
     console.log("success!");
  }else{
     console.log("bummer");
  }
  
}
```

Comparing two slots of two arrays doesn't seem to work :(
Thanks!

Comment: You are using `===` - the input from `prompt` is a string, so `1 === "1" //false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `prompt` method returns strings while your answers are numbers. Just let the loose comparison do the work by replacing strict `===` with `==`.

```js
    
var questions =[
  ['how many states?', 1],
  ['how many continents?', 2],
  ['how many legs?', 3]
]

var answers = [];
var rightAnswers = [];
var wrongAnswers = [];


for(i = 0; i<questions.length; i+=1){  
  answers.push(prompt(questions[i][0]).toLowerCase());
  
  if(questions[i][1] == answers[i]){
     // rightAnswers.push(questions[i][0]) 
     console.log("success!");
  }else{
     console.log("bummer");
  }
  
}
```

Comment: or if OP wants it to be more explicit, they could use `Number(answers.push(prompt(questions[i][0]).toLowerCase()))`;